# Log4Net working locally but not on remote Azure DB

Tags: asp.net, azure, log4net, castle-windsor

I locally develop an ASP.NET MVC application and use Log4Net to log message on the local database with the following connection string (log4net.config):

```
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" />
```

This is perfectly working (database entries are appearing in the Log table).

Now I'd like to log to remote azure database server, so I just changed the connection string into following:

```
<connectionString value="Data Source=mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=username@mydb;Password=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" />
```

I inserted my IP address in the firewall (as proof I can connect via SQL Studio on my machine to the azure db instance).

When debugging the application I don't see any exception caused by log4net.

I use castle-windsor to inject the ILogger where needed, here is my Installer:

```
public class LoggerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net().WithConfig("Configuration\\log4net.config"));
        }
    }
```

The database on the azure DB instance is the exact copy of the local one (same create script).

But nothing appears in the remote database. What am I doing wrong? How can I find out the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4net will never throw an exception if it fails. It is designed to not interact with you application. The fastest way of finding why lognet is not logging is by enabling the interal log4net logging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

OR

```
<configuration>
...

<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add 
                name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>

...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to the following problem: clustered index missing on table, just by adding the index solved the problem!